# Captcha works locally but not on Google AppEngine deployed version

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am facing issue with my flask application that contains a captcha to contact admin by mail.

How should I handle the secrets contained in my `.env` file locally (this file is getting ignored when using `gcloud app deploy`) and contains the captcha keys

```
CAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY='zzzzz'
CAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY='wwwww-A'
EMAIL_SERVER='smtp.office365.com'
EMAIL_PORT=500
EMAIL_USER='contact@my website.com'
EMAIL_PASS=''
```

That's how I get those keys in my `config.py`

```
RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY= os.getenv('CAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY')
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY=os.getenv('CAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY')
```

Comment: Have you followed the steps mentioned in the [document](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/set-up-google-cloud)?